# How to delete multiple or all rows in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to delete multiple rows or all rows in Database using `DataGridView`. 
For example. If I have 10 rows in the `DataGridView`, then all the 10 rows should be selected and deleted. Here is my code for deleting single row in database using `DataGridView`.

```
private void btnDeleteProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"];
        string connectionString = conSettings.ConnectionString;

            if (ProductServicesDataGrid.CurrentRow.Selected)
            {
                string selectedCode = ProductServicesDataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ProductServices where ProductCode='" + selectedCode + "' ", conn);
                    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    loadProductServicesTable();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Row is not Selected");
            }
    }
```

Can someone please help me and modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you shouldn't use `CurrentRow` property because it returns only one row. Instead. Use `SelectedRows` collection and iterate through it.

Second, **NEVER** concatenate parameters in command text. Instead, use parametrized query.

```
//connection.Open is moved out of the loop, to avoid unnecessary open/close
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

try
{
    foreach (var row in ProductServicesDataGrid.SelectedRows)
    {
        string selectedCode = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ProductServices where ProductCode=@productCode", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(.Parameters.Add("productCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = selectedCode;
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //this probably shouldn't be here, but outside the foreach loop.
            //that way table will be loaded after deletion of those n rows.
            //loadProductServicesTable();


    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}

//refresh products after deletion
loadProductServicesTable();
```

Comment: I guess it would be adviseable to open and close the connection outside of the loop, otherwise you open and close it unnecessarily

Comment: @MongZhu, that is good advice. But, the idea of deleting all rows one by one is also pretty bad...

Comment: I agree, but I forgot how it works with building a list and using the keyword `IN`.. :D otherwise I would write an answer :)

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah, i thought of that, but I'm too lazy to write it now... :)

Comment: He could try the duplicate that I just found.

Comment: @Nino, This worked for me though. Just want to ask why parametrized query and not concatenate parameters? Does this conflict or something else?

Comment: @Hamms read about [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)... also, obligatory [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/327/)